# Saving each row of a .xlsx file to .txt

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 300+ rows and only one column. I need to save each row (more precisely each cell since i use only one column) to different .txt files, every single one with the name of its cell. For example, if in A1 i have "pizza", the result should be a .txt file named "pizza" which contains only the word "pizza". After that A2 with "apples", A3, A4... And so on, until the end. It would be possible? I ask here because i'm pretty new with this and don't have anyone else to ask. Thank you everyone.

Edit: i tried this but doesn't work. Don't know what i'm doing wrong, if i made a mistake in the path part or something. And i don't have duplicates, i checked.
I really can't be more detailed than this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTextFileForEachRow()
Dim Fso As Object: Set Fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Dim Txt As Object
Dim row As Long, Lr As Long
Dim Val As String

Dim DestinationFolder As String
DestinationFolder = "C:\users" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\"

With ActiveSheet
    Lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To Lr
        Val = .Cells(row, "A")
        Set Txt = Fso.CreateTextFile(DestinationFolder & Val & ".txt", True)
        Txt.WriteLine (Val)
        Txt.Close
    Next row

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you done any research or made an attempt to start some code? One thing you will surely need to check for (unless systematically done upstream) is to ensure no duplicate cells or have something in place to handle duplicates

Comment: Not bad. I think the only mistake is that you have a missing backslash ("\") in the first part of `DestinationFolder`. It should be `"C:\Users\"`. It would be also advisable to use e.g. `r` instead of `row`, because `row` messes up the `Row.Property` e.g. in `...End(xlUp).Row`. Also `Val` is a `VBA` function, so rather use e.g. `cVal`. I would also rather use the `Value` property here: `cVal = .Cells(r, "A").Value`.

Answer (score 1):

### Create Text Files From Cell Values

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub CreateTextFileForEachRow()
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim Txt As Object
    Dim cRow As Long, Lr As Long
    Dim cVal As String
    
    Dim DestinationFolder As String
    DestinationFolder = "C:\users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\"
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For cRow = 2 To Lr
            cVal = .Cells(cRow, "A").Value
            Set Txt = fso.CreateTextFile(DestinationFolder & cVal & ".txt", True)
            Txt.WriteLine (cVal)
            Txt.Close
        Next cRow
    End With

End Sub
```

- Before using any of the following two versions, adjust the values in their constants sections. If necessary use `Dim` instead of `Const`. `DestinationFolder` is `FolderPath` in these solutions.

**Compact**

```
Sub createTextFiles()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2021\65565907\Files"
    Const FileExtension As String = ".txt"
    Const wbPath As String = "F:\Test\2021\65565907\Test.xlsx"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    ' Open Source Workbook.
    'With ActiveSheet
    With Workbooks.Open(wbPath).Worksheets(wsName).Range(FirstCellAddress)
        ' Attempt to define the Last-Non Empty Cell.
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Find( _
            What:="*", _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        ' Validate Last Non-Empty Cell.
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Define Source Range.
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
        ' Write values from Source Column Range to Data Array (2D).
        If rng.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
            Data = rng.Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
        End If
        .Worksheet.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False ' Reconsider if ActiveSheet.
    End With
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       ' Write unique values from Data Array (2D) to Unique Dictionary.
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            cValue = Data(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(cValue) Then
                If Not IsEmpty(cValue) Then
                    .Item(cValue) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        ' Validate Unique Dictionary.
        If .Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Write values from keys of Unique Dictionary to Data Array (1D).
        Data = .Keys
    End With
    
    ' Create and write to the files.
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For i = 0 To UBound(Data)
            With .CreateTextFile( _
                    .BuildPath(FolderPath, Data(i) & FileExtension), True)
                .WriteLine Data(i)
                .Close
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Files created.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
    ' Navigate to folder path in File Explorer.
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FolderPath

End Sub
```

**Refactored**

```
Sub createTextFilesRefactored()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2021\65565907\Files"
    Const FileExtension As String = "txt"
    Const wbPath As String = "F:\Test\2021\65565907\Test.xlsx"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const Cols As String = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim Unique As Variant
    
    ' Data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Workbooks.Open(wbPath).Worksheets(wsName)
        Set rng = defineNonEmptyColumnRange(.Columns(Cols), FirstRow)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
        Data = getRange(rng)
        .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Unique
    Unique = UniqueToArray(Data)
    If IsEmpty(Unique) Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Result
    createAndWriteToTextFilesFromArray Unique, FolderPath, FileExtension
    MsgBox "Files created.", vbInformation, "Success"
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FolderPath

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Defines the range of a range containing data (values): from
'               the first row (not necessarily containing data) to the last row
'               containing data.
' Remarks:      Usually the first row is known i.e. determined 'manually'.
'               If it isn't, omitting 'FirstRow' or setting it to 0
'               will trigger its calculation.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function defineNonEmptyColumnRange( _
    rng As Range, _
    Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 0) _
As Range
    
    Const ProcName As String = "defineNonEmptyColumnRange"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim pRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Select Case FirstRow
        Case Is < 0, Is > rng.Rows.Count
        Case 0
            Set cel = rng.Find( _
                What:="*", _
                After:=rng(rng.CountLarge), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If cel Is Nothing Then
                GoTo ProcExit
            End If
            Set pRng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - cel.Row) _
                .Offset(cel.Row - rng.Row)
            Set cel = Nothing
        Case 1
            Set pRng = rng
        Case Else
            Set pRng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1) _
                .Offset(FirstRow - 1)
    End Select
    Set cel = pRng.Find( _
        What:="*", _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If cel Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    Set defineNonEmptyColumnRange = pRng.Resize(cel.Row - pRng.Row + 1)

ProcExit:
    Exit Function

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values from a range to a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getRange( _
    rng As Range) _
As Variant
     
    Const ProcName As String = "getRange"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    If rng.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
 
    getRange = Data

ProcExit:
    Exit Function

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the unique values from a 2D array
'               to a 1D zero-based array, excluding error and empty values.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function UniqueToArray( _
    TwoD As Variant) _
As Variant
    
    Const ProcName As String = "UniqueToArray"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If IsEmpty(TwoD) Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim cLower As Long: cLower = LBound(TwoD, 2)
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(TwoD, 2)
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For i = LBound(TwoD, 1) To UBound(TwoD, 1)
            For j = cLower To cUpper
                cValue = TwoD(i, j)
                If Not IsError(cValue) Then
                    If Not IsEmpty(cValue) Then
                        .Item(cValue) = Empty
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        If .Count > 0 Then
            UniqueToArray = .Keys
        End If
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates text files named by values from an array and at
'               the same time writes the same value to the text file.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub createAndWriteToTextFilesFromArray( _
        OneD As Variant, _
        ByVal FolderPath As String, _
        Optional ByVal FileExtension As String = "txt")
    
    Const ProcName As String = "createAndWriteToTextFilesFromArray"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If IsEmpty(OneD) Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim n As Long
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
            .CreateFolder (FolderPath)
        End If
        For n = LBound(OneD) To UBound(OneD)
            On Error Resume Next ' File name validation maybe more appropriate.
            With .CreateTextFile( _
                    .BuildPath(FolderPath, OneD(n) & "." & FileExtension), True)
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    .WriteLine OneD(n)
                    .Close
                End If
            End With
            On Error GoTo clearError
        Next n
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```